# xml to excel 2003 issue with datetime

Tags: c#, xml, excel

I am using XML to generate Excel 2003 dynamically.

All works good, but when I am trying to put datetime with data type = "DateTime", excel is not generating and it is throwing error.

```
sw.Write("<Cell ss:StyleID=\"s21\"><Data ss:Type=\"DateTime\">" + Convert.ToDateTime(dsReportData.Rows[i]["close_time"]).ToString("M/D/YYYY H:MM") + "</Data></Cell>\r\n");
sw.Write("<Cell ss:StyleID=\"s22\"><Data ss:Type=\"String\">" + dsReportData.Rows[i]["close_time"].ToString() + "</Data></Cell>\r\n");
```

First line code throws error, while the 2nd works perfect, but I want as a data type = "DateTime".

Is there any work around?

Comment: Whats the exact error message?

Answer (score 0):

Why Data ss:Type=\ "DateTime\" when you are converting it to string data type here

```
Convert.ToDateTime(dsReportData.Rows[i]["close_time"]).ToString("M/D/YYYY H:MM") ?
```

Also format you specified must be replaced. Replace

```
"M/D/YYYY H:MM" with "M d yyyy H:MM" or "M/d/yyyy H:MM".
```

**As the format is case sensitive**

To keep DateTime type use:

```
Convert.ToDateTime((Convert.ToDateTime(dsReportData.Rows[i]["close_time"])).ToString("M d 
yyyy H:MM"));
```